# What is the nature of accumulating/iterating recursively and IO operations within a function of type 'IO a'?

Tags: haskell

...assuming `a` is some type e.g. [Int], and we want to iterate e.g. taking all elements, operate on them and print the result after the operations, like operations take place in the following code:

```
fa :: [Int] -> [Int]
fa [] = []
fa (n:rln) = (n + 1) : fa rln
```

...but with in a function of a type like

```
fb :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
```

...such that

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do
        fb [3, 2, 6, 8] >>= print
```

...would print the given list in order ([4, 3, 7, 9]) and again print the result.

### Differentiation and Background

I would like to understand the nature of type 'IO a'.

This question is **not** about how to iterate with ready to use functions like folds and fmap.

This is **not** a question about whether it makes sense to print and return the same result.

### Code so far

So far I have got this "beast":

```
f :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
f ln = f' ln >>= print >>= return (f' ln)
    where
        f' :: [Int] -> IO [Int]
        f' [] = return []
        f' (n:rln) = f' rln >>= (\r -> return ((n + 1) : r))
```

...which can be applied in main like this

```
main :: IO ()
main = f [3, 2, 6, 8] >>= (putStrLn . (\r -> "result=" ++ show r))
```

...prints:

```
[4,3,7,9]
result=[4,3,7,9]
```

For me, suspicious is the line `f ln = f' ln >>= print >>= return (f' ln)` that does not pass the result of `f' ln` to return.

### Question(s)

What is the nature of type `IO a`?

In particular:

- Is it correct to say that a function of type `IO a` always has to `return` type `a`?
- As we can see we can perform `IO ()` operations in a function of type `IO a` - but do we really have to have such a clumsy code if we print in such functions?
- What would be the most effective implementation?
- Should we generally avoid the dual use (IO operations and recursive computations) in one function?

Comment: `f' ln >>= print >>= return (f' ln)` is  _very_ misleading, since the `return` uses another monad than IO! Indeed, after `>>=` we need a function so that `return` uses the `(->) a` monad. Also, you don't want to execute `f' ln` twice. I'd suggest to use a lambda as in `f' ln >>= \x -> print x >> return x`, or use do-notation `do x <- f' ln ; print x ; return x` for clarity.

Comment: If you’re not already aware, it might help to realize that `return` is just a (poorly named) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For me, suspicious is the line `f ln = f' ln >>= print >>= return (f' ln)` that does not pass the result of `f' ln` to return.

I agree, that seems clearly wrong. Perhaps you want this instead:

```
f ln = f' ln >>= \x -> print x >> return x
```

There are various other ways to say the same thing.

> Is it correct to say that a function of type `IO a` always has to `return` type `a`?

No, for a couple reasons. First: a value of type `IO a` is not a function! Second: it's not the case that an `IO a` action always returns; for example `exitWith ExitSuccess` doesn't. Finally, and most critically: `return` is not the only way to end an `IO` action, as there are many other base actions. For example, `getChar` is an `IO` action and does not call `return` -- it is implemented as a primitive by the compiler.<sup>*</sup> An action of type `IO a` is always allowed to finalize itself by calling some other action of type `IO a` to finish, including compiler primitives, instead of `return`ing a value of type `a`.

> As we can see we can perform `IO ()` operations in a function of type `IO a` - but do we really have to have such a clumsy code if we print in such functions?

I don't know. I don't know what you consider clumsy. If you can make this question more objective, I'd be happy to take a stab at answering it.

> What would be the most effective implementation?

I would write `main = mapM foo [3, 2, 6, 8] >>= print`. If you don't allow me to use `mapM` from the standard library, I would implement it first, e.g. as

```
mapM f [] = return []
mapM f (x:xs) = do
    y <- f x
    ys <- mapM f xs
    return (y:ys)
```

> Should we generally avoid the dual use (IO operations and recursive computations) in one function?

No, IO and recursive computations love each other; almost every `main` I've ever written mixed `IO` and recursion.

<sup>*</sup> Okay, I don't actually know whether `getChar` calls `return`. It might. But if it does, it is because there is some other, more primitive thing that it calls which does not end with a `return`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried `main = mapM foo [3, 2, 6, 8] >>= print` but it doesn't compile.

Comment: How would `mapM` look like if it would print the result and return the result, as f does?

Comment: If you don't mind I apply the idea of mapM to a function that would compile and fit to the context. Please, re-correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann `foo` would not print the result; the `print` afterwards does that. An example `foo` would be `foo x = return (x+1)`... though if that were your *actual* `foo` then I would just write `main = print (map (1+) [3, 2, 6, 8])` instead and completely skip the monad machinery.

Comment: Please see, here, the challenge is to have a recursive function with type `IO a` and IO operation in this function. If I didn't make this clear enough then I have to edit the question. To also print the result inside is just an example of an IO operation.

Comment: @JörgBrüggmann `foo x = return (x+1)` is an `IO` operation, and can be used with this recursive definition. If I didn't make this clear enough then I have to edit the answer. And the joy of types is that you may substitute any other `IO` operation with the same type, doing whatever you want inside, including printing or reading from disk or playing chess online and know that it will still work.